# Facebook iPad App and viewing Facebook page tabs

Tags: facebook, ipad, facebook-apps, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

I'm aware that Facebook (custom) Iframe tabs can be viewed on the iPad via the Safari browser. Does anyone know if there is a way to view custom page tabs within the iPad Facebook App? If not, is there a workaround solution? Kind regards, Daniel